# Get properties of a given DBpedia category

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to get `skos:broader` of a given DBpedia category, but it gives me a `null` result.

This is my SPARQL request:

```
  select ?value where { 
     <http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Watches> skos:broader ?value 
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URI for DBpedia resources is `http://dbpedia.org/resource/<title>`, it's not `http://dbpedia.org/page/<title>`, that's the URL of the DBpedia page describing the resource.

So, your query should be:

```
select ?value where { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Watches> skos:broader ?value 
}
```

Or shorter:

```
select ?value where { 
  dbc:Watches skos:broader ?value 
}
```

Comment: Works, Thank you so much